# library(pryr) returns a message. Registered S3 method overwritten by 'pryr': method from print.bytes Rcpp

Tags: r, pryr

When I active a package called `pryr`. It returns a message

```
    library(pryr)

    Registered S3 method overwritten by 'pryr':
    method      from   
    print.bytes Rcpp.
```

I would like to know what does it is mean?
However the package runs properly. That message shows only one time each session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that both `Rcpp` and `pryr` have an S3 method (a function) called `print.bytes`. That is, a `print` method for an object of the `bytes` class.

Since you now loaded `pryr`, the function from `pryr` will be used, not the one from `Rcpp`.

This might mean that objects of class `bytes` will be displayed differently after loading `pryr`, but since it's just a print method, this is unlikely to  have serious consequences.