# Unable to open the R/Cape Package

Tags: r

Currently running R version 3.6.2 and RStudio version 1.2.5033 (both the latest versions as of today).

I have installed the R/Cape package from  https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cape, although when I try to load the package into R studio using:

```
library(cape)
```

I get the following from the RStudio console. RStudio then stops responding. I have tried this in just R as well and R also stops responding.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Can anybody please tell me if they've had any similar experiences and how they resolved them? Or if you've managed to install the 'cape' package how you did so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'cape' library depends on other packages like 'htmltools' and many others. This is not an error message, just a warning. It means that some of the functions from 'tools:rstudio' will be replaced by other functions with the same name. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093732/librarypryr-returns-a-message-registered-s3-method-overwritten-by-pryr-met) which already addresses this.

As for the non-responsive behaviour, it is probably unrelated to the warnings discussed above.  Try reinstalling R and updating all your packages.  In Rstudio, you can update all your packages by clicking Tools > Update Packages > Select All > Install Updates.