# R LANGUAGE: Registered S3 method overwritten by 'data.table':

Tags: r, package, plotly, dashboard, cran

I'm using 3.6.3 R version. while compiling R.mrd i got this errors:
`Registered S3 method overwritten by 'data.table':
  method           from
  print.data.table

Registered S3 method overwritten by 'htmlwidgets':
  method           from

  print.htmlwidget tools:rstudio
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'dplyr':
  method           from
  print.rowwise_df 
le package �flexdashboard� a �t� compil� avec la version R 3.6.3Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'htmltools':
  method               from

  print.html           tools:rstudio
  print.shiny.tag      tools:rstudio
  print.shiny.tag.list tools:rstudio`
Therefore plots didn't appear in a dashboard.
Any help please

Comment: This is usually caused by multiple packages having the same named functions. Have a look at this answer - it offers some insight into your query https://stackoverflow.com/a/59093803/8158951

Answer (score 5):

This is usually caused by multiple packages having the same named functions. Have a look at this answer - it offers some insight into your query https://stackoverflow.com/a/59093803/8158951

In your case, the last loaded package is taking precedence for the function name of the one you need to plot.

It would assist if you can provide a reproducible example with the code you are using, but I'll try and provide some guidance.

Where duplicate function names occur, R provides a warning like the one you refer to above. This can be mitigated by adding the name of the required package before the function call as follows `PackageName::FunctionName`.

If plotting is an issue for you, and assuming you are using ggplot, you could try this:

```
ggplot2::ggplot()
```